# Grails - RabbitMQ and listener - too more onMessage call

Tags: spring, mongodb, grails, rabbitmq, spring-aop

At first I have application where I'm using RabbitMQ and Grails.
I defined listeners:

```
<bean id="rabbitListenerCreateDocument" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="queues" ref="rabbitQueuePageInstanceCreated" />
        <property name="defaultRequeueRejected" value="false"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="createPageService" />
        <property name="errorHandler" ref="errorHandlerService" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="mongoTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="0" />
 </bean>
```

The problem is that onMessage method from createPageService run too more times.
I think because I got this error (when I turn onlogs from spring):

```
connection error; reason: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.UnknownChannelException: Unknown channel number 10
```

After some time I got that spring dosnt send ack to rabbit when this exception was thrown.
Everything should look fine, but...
In'm method onMessage I'm creating document in MongoDB - and I'm geting too much documents - it CRITICAL in my app.
I'm using Mongo to store some objects, and as we all know MongoDB is not transactional.
I think that scenario looks like this:

1. Listener getting message
2. method onMessage from createPageService is running
3. method creating document in Mongo
4. method onMessage reach to end
5. Spring want to send ACK to rabbit but it get UnknownChannelException
6. TransactionManager want to rollback but it can't - there is no transaction on MongoDB
7. The same message came one more time and now everything works ok (there is no Exception)

I trying to make some modification to solve this but it doesn’t works:
1. First I'm trying to add Around aspect on onMessage method - it dosnt works ... I'm getting:

`Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut`

1. I define new transaction manager for connection for bean: createPageService. It not work's too..

Somebody have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: I've found that using spring-integration to abstract the rabbit stuff in Grails leads to simplified configuration. You can use a `gateway` for putting messages on the channel and a `service-activator` to handle messages coming of the queue. We are using this approach and really don't have to deal with the queue or onMessage at all. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this plugin for grails without issues:
https://github.com/pablomolnar/rabbit-ha

It has some extra configuration, but for basics it should be enough.